# React Native - Bridge Android Native to React Native get Slow Performance

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm new in bridging Native (Android) to React Native.

I want to send a lot of data from Android Native to React Native but get performance issues (slow).

Here my example code :

**Android Native (using callback):**

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000000000000 ; i++){    
this.dispatchEvent("MyEvent","hello this is my message");
}
```

**React Native :**

```
var myFunction = (tags) => {
            console.log("Message :"+tags);
}

RNTry.on("MyEvent", myFunction);
```

What result i get :

1. Message from Android Native send to React Native with success result
2. React Native UI freeze, not responding when i touch a button

**My Question :**

> How to send a lot of data (real time) from Android Native to React
> Native without get React Native UI freeze/lag?

Comment: try run it outside of main thread, use handler or async task. But send alot data in events is obviously slow with the current arch, with turbo modules it should be better.

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz : what is turbo modules mean?

Comment: is the future architecture of react native https://formidable.com/blog/2019/fabric-turbomodules-part-3/

Comment: I already use async task, Android Native fine, but React Native that receive message almost real time get slow in UI. Any idea ? @anthonywillismuñoz

Comment: there is not, did you try with for with 100 only ? if you get same results ? also remember to shutdown debugger etc it lag javascript

Comment: 100 no problem. large number and fast callback only. @anthonywillismuñoz

Answer (score 0):

try to send events from android to react

```
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                      String eventName,
                      @Nullable WritableMap params) {
 reactContext
     .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
     .emit(eventName, params);
}
```

read about it
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android